# How to compute the product of six numbers on Assembly Language

Tags: visual-studio-2012, assembly, x86, cpu-registers

I am new to assembly and I am trying to create a program that simply multiplies the product 1 * 2 * 3 * 4 * 5 * 6 and stores that result in the `AL` register. I am told that I can accomplish this in a single statement.

This is what I have so far:

```
MOV product, 1 * 2 * 3 * 4 * 5 * 6
MOV al, product
```

However, this produces the message `error A2070: inval` on the first line.
I also tried to do it like this:

```
IMUL AH, 1, 2
IMUL BH, 3, 4
IMUL BL, 5, 6
IMUL CL, BH, BL
IMUL AL, CL, AH
```

But every line of that produces an error referring to the size of the arguments being different.

Could someone tell me the best way I can accomplish computing this product?

Comment: What's wrong with just typing `720` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that `1*2*3*4*5*6 = 720` so it won't fit into a 8 bit register so you should use a 16 bit one, such as `ax`. If you are allowed to use compile time multiply, then of course `mov ax, 1*2*3*4*5*6` should work. The assembler simply turns that into `mov ax, 720`, no surprise there.

As for the second version, `IMUL` does not accept two immediate operands. If you want to use this approach, you will need something like this:

```
mov ax, 2
imul ax, ax, 3
imul ax, ax, 4
imul ax, ax, 5
imul ax, ax, 6
```